# The changing a color of image (rescale). Scikit-image

Tags: python, matplotlib, scikit-image

Why does the color of image change when I use rescale in scikit image?

[image]

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from skimage.transform import rescale

im = imread('C:/abc.jpg')
plt.imshow(im)
plt.show()

im_rescaled = rescale(im , 0.25)
plt.imshow(im_rescaled)
plt.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rescale` doesn't know that you have passed a 2D color image. When you load it in, it is an array of shape (100, 100, 3), where the 3 elements of the final axis are the red, green, and blue channels. `rescale` rescales along *all* axes by default, so you end up with an image of shape (25, 25, 1). Matplotlib ignores this final axis and renders it as a grayscale image using its default colormap, viridis, which is why it looks green.

In order to make rescale work only across the rows and column axes, and not along the channels axis, use

```py
im_rescaled = rescale(im, 0.25, multichannel=True)
```

This will give you a rescaled image of shape (25, 25, 3) will all three color channels as expected.

You can read more about the rescale API in the [scikit-image API docs](https://scikit-image.org/docs/stable/api/skimage.transform.html#skimage.transform.rescale).

Comment: thank you. I would like to know "rescale" just zoom image? For example, 0.25 means that image will be zoomed 4 times?

Comment: depends what you mean by "zoom" but I think so: approximately, every pixel in the returned image will correspond to 16 (4x4) in the original image.

Comment: I just need to enlarge image 4 times

Comment: so then you probably want `rescale(im, 4, multichannel=True)`?

Comment: It's strange. Because it didn't work before it. But now I don't see any change for image. As I understand image should lose quality. I think that I should see more pixels in image as result of resсale?

Comment: Are you sure you are not seeing more pixels? Try `print(im.shape, im_rescaled.shape)`, for both options.

Comment: If I enlarge image 5 times I see: (366, 400, 3) (500, 500, 3)

Comment: That is weird. Perhaps you can ask another question with a specific image (please share the source image on imgur.com) and complete code?

Answer (score 2):

Note that in newer version of scikit image, you have to use `channel_axis` parameter instead of `multichannel`. So the command becomes like the below line assuming the third channel is the channel axis (which is the most common)

```py
im_rescaled = rescale(im, 0.25, channel_axis=2)
```